# Выбор принтера при печати excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

При печати `excel` необходимо дать возможность выбрать принтер. Но при установки принтера получаю исключение `COMException(0x800A03EC)`

```
using interopExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// код .....

interopExcel.Worksheet ws = (interopExcel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets["паспорт"];

// Print out 1 copy to the default printer:
ws.PrintOut(
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// здесь пытаюсь установить имя нужного принтера, и здесь получаю исключение
excelApp.ActivePrinter = sPrinterName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, нашёл ответ здесь:

[Метод - **Worksheet.PrintOut** - Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel | Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.printout.aspx)

```
ws.PrintOut(
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    sPrinterName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// excelApp.ActivePrinter = sPrinterName;
```